# Parsing html tag link with Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

I want to copy the content of the first tag (the link) to the next 2 tags:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://website.com/en/america.html" />
```

to

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https:/something-better/rosrr.html"/>

"@id": "https://distrinct.com/stiintess-pomei.html"
```

**Output:**

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://website.com/en/america.html" />

<meta property="og:url" content="https://website.com/en/america.html"/>

"@id": "https://website.com/en/america.html"
```

**I really don't know why my Powershell code is not working as I want:**

```
$sourcedir = "C:\Folder1\"
$resultsdir = "C:\Folder1\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcedir -Filter *.html | ForEach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Raw
    $replaceValue = (Select-String -InputObject $content -Pattern '(?<=<link rel="canonical" href=").+(?=" />)').Matches.Value
    $content = $content -replace '(<meta property="og:url" content=").+("/>)',$replaceValue
    $content = $content -replace '("@id": ").+(")',$replaceValue
    Set-Content -Path $resultsdir\$($_.name) $content
}
```

**This is what I get, instead of the Output I want:**

[image: I get]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. To make a parsing in Powershell, with regex, must use the same "start" and the same "stop". And you have to pay attention to the regex formula:

```
$sourcedir = "C:\Folder1\"
$resultsdir = "C:\Folder1\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcedir -Filter *.html | ForEach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Raw
    $replaceValue = (Select-String -InputObject $content -Pattern '(?<=<link rel="canonical" href=").*(")').Matches.Value
    $content = $content -replace '(?<=<meta property="og:url" content=").*(")',$replaceValue
    $content = $content -replace '(?<="@id": ").*(")',$replaceValue
    Set-Content -Path $resultsdir\$($_.name) $content
}
```